# Trying to implement preview of image in Angular using flow

Tags: angular, ng-flow

```
<img flow-img="blobImage" flow-init>
```

- The blobImage variable contains the base64 string of an image.
- Am i missing something or syntax error ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img flow-img="$flow.files[0]" />
```

or

```html
<img flow-img="$blobImage" flow-init />
```